# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" when trying to get the username of a user in "guildMemberAdd"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get the username of a new member in a discord server. However, I found out that `member` is actually of type `object` instead of `GuildMember`, so I am getting an error when trying to access `member.user.username`.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    print(typeof member);
    const username = member.user.username;
    var channel = member.guild.channels.get('598668119849959426');//get('589517896749940739')
    if (username.toLowerCase().includes("potato")) {
      channel.send("The evil spuds have sent " + username + " to continue the Potato Invasion!");
    } else if (username.toLowerCase().includes("berry")) {
      channel.send(username + " is a berry good fellow");
    } else {
      // idk some random stuff
    }
});
```

The error:

```
    const username = member.user.username;
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

I expect it to simply do as it should.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using? Can you confirm that `member instanceof Discord.GuildMember` returns `true` (assuming `Discord` is your variable requiring the Discord.js package)? `typeof` would be correct to say that `member` is an object even if it is a GuildMember.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // Send the message to a designated channel on a server:
    console.log('A New Member has joined the Discord');
  const channel = client.channels.get(welcomeChat);
  // Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
  if (!channel) return;
  // Send the message, mentioning the member
  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member} Please read the following 
for access to the Server.`);
]);
```

Comment: set a variable called userName, call the user's name how I did within my channel.send and do your checks to see if the users name contains potato, or whatever you are looking for.

Comment: A. If [`member.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) is undefined in the author's case, they won't be able to read the username. This code simply avoids using the property rather than addressing the problem. B. Converting a GuildMember or User to a string will result in the template of their *mention* (for example, `<@189855563893571595>`), not their actual username.